# My ng-option select bar is showing the last value in the list

Tags: html, angularjs, html-select, ng-options, angularjs-select

Here is my HTML

```html
<select ng-if="list[$index].length>0" data-ng-model="form1value[$index]"
        data-ng-options="label for label in obj.child track by $index">
</select>
```

I am getting the last value in obj.child as selected by default. I want to write 'select' in the select bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach (--Select-- will be the default selected option):

```
<select ng-if="list[$index].length>0"  data-ng-model="form1value[$index]">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in obj.child track by $index" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

0"  data-ng-model="form1value[$index]" ng-options="item.value as item.name in obj.child" class="form-control">

Comment: No need to add <option> serately, use ng-option